Circuitikz: Access anchors for connection points of wire for inductors
I am trying to access the point of an inductor where the wire connects in circuitikz. I can't find a name for the anchors in the documentation (do they even exist?) and  I tried to help me out with the plain tikz anchors. But as you can see in the result there is a gap, which I don't want. Has someone ever tried this or can tell me, if it's even possible?
Thanks a lot!
To show what I mean:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[americaninductors]{circuitikz}

\tikzset{measure/.style={circuitikz/inductors/coils = 2,circuitikz/inductors/width = 0.35}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
    \node (SO) [rectangle, draw] at (0,0) {SO};
    \coordinate[node distance = 1.5cm, left = of SO] (l) {};
    \coordinate[node distance = 1.5cm, right = of SO] (r) {};
    \draw (l) to[short] (SO)
        (r) -- (SO);
    \node (l_i) [americaninductorshape,measure,yshift = -0.1cm] at ($(SO.west)!0.5!(l)$) {};
    \node (r_i) [americaninductorshape,measure,yshift = -0.1cm] at ($(SO.east)!0.5!(r)$) {};
    \draw (l_i.south east) -- ++ (0,-1) node (l_m) {} -| (r_i.south west)
        (l_i.south west) -- ++ (0,-3) node (l_u) {} -| (r_i.south east);
    \coordinate (m_o) at (SO |- l_m) {};
    \coordinate (m_u) at (SO |- l_u) {};
    \node (I) [rectangle, draw] at ($(m_o)!0.5!(m_u)$) {$\Delta I>$};
    \draw (m_o) to [short,*-] (I)
        (m_u) to [short,*-] (I);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

that gives me:


Have you tried left and right? (I can't now, will post a complete answer soon)

@Rmano thank you, that makes it better. The height is now perfect, although the lines are still offset horizontally (the same way like you can see in my picture). But I suppose I have to correct that manually whith something like half of the linewidth?

You can use left and right anchors, but as you noticed you have a problem here (using a minimum example):
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[americaninductors]{circuitikz}

\tikzset{measure/.style={circuitikz/inductors/coils = 2,circuitikz/inductors/width = 0.35}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (l_i) [americaninductorshape,measure,yshift = -0.1cm] at (0,0) {};
    \draw (l_i.left) -- ++(0,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


...which is arguably a bug of the package (the anchor point should be in the center of the thick line), but since it has been like that forever, and for a lot of devices, I do not know if I can change it. I will look into it when I have time... but don't hold your breath.

Thanks, I can probably use that and correct the horizontal shift myself.

The cute inductor anchors appear to be off by the same 0.4pt (line thinckness).
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[americaninductors]{circuitikz}

\tikzset{measure/.style={circuitikz/inductors/coils = 2,circuitikz/inductors/width = 0.35}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (I) [americaninductorshape,measure] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[red] (I.north east) -- (I.north west) -- (I.south west) -- (I.south east) -- cycle;
    \draw[red] (I.east) -- (I.west)  (I.north) -- (I.south);
    \draw (I.left) ++(-.4pt,0pt) -- ++(0,-.5);
    \draw (I.right) ++(.4pt,0pt) -- ++(0,-.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

